# Magento updates/patches

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, patches

Right now I'm running **Magento ver. 1.9.2.4** which is quite old.

If I would download and update/patch my Magento from [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html) do I still need to patch 1.9.3 first or can I just update directly to the latest version?

**EDIT:**
**It was the wrong link! Check the link again, sorry for the inconvenience.**

Comment: This applies to you if your **Magento** version is earlier than EE 1.14.1.0 or **CE 1.9.1.0**. You do not need to apply this patch, you are running on 1.9.2.4

Comment: do you want to upgrade the magento version or do you want to install the security pathes?

If you upgrade your magento version to the latest version then all the security patches will be there.

But if  you want to install the security patches then your magento version  remain the same.

Comment: It was the wrong link! Check the link again, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

The Patch you are going to apply have details about the dependencies with the other patches if the dependent patches were already in your Magento instance you can apply the update either you need to first check the dependencies and apply them one by one till the latest version.

Comment: It was the wrong link! Check the link again, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to continue using 1.9.2.4 you should check **app/etc/applied.patches** file and see which patches you have and compare them to the magento patch downloads page. In short, install missing patches, I would assume there would be a handful of them.

Easiest way, simply update to **1.9.3.7** which is the latest Magento 1.x version, it will have ALL necessary patches in place. 
As usual, before any update make sure to apply them on **test site** and check if all extensions work as expected.